# Spring Batch : about XML to XML transform

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch, dozer

I am considering using Spring Batch framework to migrate content from source (xml file) to a target (xml file in a different format). should I build my own `ItemProcessor` ? I'm reading from one content management that stores docs in xml, and I want to save to another content management also in xml, but a different format, how can I do xml to xml transformation ?

Answer (score 0):

While probably not required, the easier approach would be to build your own `ItemProcessor`.  Spring Batch delegates the XML generation to the marshalling framework of your choice so in theory, you could take the domain object you read in and map it to the new format, but it's typically the easiest to structure the domain object to look similar to the XML structure you're generating.  In that case, you'll need an `ItemProcessor` to do the conversion.